# Injecting session bean into request bean redeploy problems

Tags: spring, jsf, liferay

I've run into a problem when trying to inject a session-scoped bean into a request-scoped bean. I've included a MWE at the end of this post and tried to pinpoint the exact situation in which the module stops working.

The first time I deploy the module (which is actually a Liferay portlet) with the injected session-scoped bean, everything works as expected. I can redeploy as much as I like, and it seems to keep on working until I actually let the container create the beans and session. From then on, every time I redeploy I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.test.sessionscope.TestSessionBean field com.test.sessionscope.TestBean.bean to com.test.sessionscope.TestSessionBean
```

Injection and scoping is accomplished using Spring, and the used servlet container is Tomcat.

A minimal (not always) working example:

**TestSessionBean**

```
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class TestSessionBean implements Serializable {

}
```

**TestBean**

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject private TestSessionBean bean;

    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        name = "session test";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        #{testBean.name}
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Comment: You are mixing CDI and Spring annotations - `@Named @Scope("request")`. Use either of them `@Named @RequestScoped` or `@Controller @Scope("request")` - (or `@Component @Scope("request")`)

Comment: Also asked here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/47995348. Please crossreference such locations yourself so that others can find answers in case they've already been given on the other platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem. Apparently it was due to a wrongly set Liferay-property (private-session-attributes was set to false instead of true).

More information can be found in this thread: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/48105922.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@Scope("session")` to `@SessionScoped`

and `@Scope("request")` to `@RequestScoped`